# how to get setup python app icon on cpanel on bluehost

Tags: python, django, cpanel, bluehost

I want to deploy django app. I tried with apache in manual and Iam failing to do that. I want to deploy through setup python app icon by following this video -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1jJPVhanzU&t=528s
But no such icon is present on my bluehost filemanager. The support chat person said that has to install from my side. Python and apache are installed on whm but how to get that icon

Answer (score -1):

it's very easy with cpanel just follow these steps in this website and your django app will work perfect

https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html